# How to set 'Description' in AWS Lambda using Chalice

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chalice

I have been using [Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice) for my [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) programming. 
There's only one thing that buggs me. How can I set the **Description** of a lambda function?

I know I can customize memory and timeout using [configuration file](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/configfile.html) in the `.chalice` directory. But I cannot find how to customize the **Description**.

[image: Web console of Lambda Code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, chalice don't have a **description** field for lambda. You can check on the master branch.

https://github.com/aws/chalice/blob/6295aeddd12c327fb0a524e47f69146daa0b9f34/chalice/awsclient.py

You can add a feature to add it to the list of attributes.

Hope it helps.